# Exportar Registros por Excel, me crea archivo dañado. Maawebsite

Tags: php, laravel, excel, maatwebsite

tengo este código bastante simple que me debería exportar un Excel, y que lo hace. Pero, el documento que me entrega siempre me da este error:

```
Excel no puede abrir el archivo, porque el formato o la extensión de este no son validos.
```

Este es el codigo que tengo:

En el controlador

```
public function excel_download() 
{
    return Excel::download(new ProductExport, 'products.xlsx');
}
```

Y en el Export

```
class ProductExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
{
use Exportable;
public function collection()
{
    return Product::get()->map(function ($product) {
        return [
            'active' => $product->status,
            'product_name' => $product->product_name,
        ];
    });
}

public function headings(): array
{
    return [
        'Active',
        'Name *',
    ];
}
}
```

Decir que me funciona perfecto para cuando quiero exportar un archivo .csv, pero ese problema pasa cuando lo intento con un formato .xlsx. Si alguien me podría ayuda, se lo agradecería

Comment: Dale una mirada a este hilo, que reporta lo mismo https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel/issues/1673#issuecomment-494050465. Prueba las opciones que mencionan ahí y comentanos los resultados

Comment: intenta guardarlo en .xls y no xlsx